# Кнопки срабатывают только после второго клика

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="assessment">
        <button id="positive" onclick="changeState()">Positive</button>
        <button id="negative" onclick="changeState()">Negative</button>
        <button id="neutral" onclick="changeState()">Neutral</button>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>

</div>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var content = document.querySelector('#content');
var positive = document.querySelector('#positive');
var negative = document.querySelector('#negative');
var neutral = document.querySelector('#neutral');

function changeState() {
    positive.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(content.textContent != null){
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        var choice = document.createElement('p');
        var choiceText = document.createTextNode('Positive choice');
        choice.appendChild(choiceText);
      document.getElementById("content").appendChild(choice);
    });
    negative.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(content.textContent != null){
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        var choice = document.createElement('p');
        choice.textContent = 'Negative choice';
        content.appendChild(choice);
    });
    neutral.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(content.textContent != null){
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        var choice = document.createElement('p');
        choice.textContent = 'Neutral choice';
        content.appendChild(choice);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому-что в первый раз, вы объявляете функцию которая добавляет события клика,а во второй раз, они уже отрабатывают. нужно функцию вызвать сначала)
1. Объявление функции. 2. Вызов функции. 3. Добавление событий к элементам внутри функции. 4. Клик по кнопке и получение желаемого результата.

```js
var content = document.querySelector('#content');
var positive = document.querySelector('#positive');
var negative = document.querySelector('#negative');
var neutral = document.querySelector('#neutral');

function changeState() {
    positive.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(content.textContent != null){
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        var choice = document.createElement('p');
        var choiceText = document.createTextNode('Positive choice');
        choice.appendChild(choiceText);
      document.getElementById("content").appendChild(choice);
    });
    negative.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(content.textContent != null){
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        var choice = document.createElement('p');
        choice.textContent = 'Negative choice';
        content.appendChild(choice);
    });
    neutral.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if(content.textContent != null){
            content.removeChild(content.firstChild);
        }
        var choice = document.createElement('p');
        choice.textContent = 'Neutral choice';
        content.appendChild(choice);
    });
}
changeState()
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="assessment">
        <button id="positive">Positive</button>
        <button id="negative">Negative</button>
        <button id="neutral">Neutral</button>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    </div>

</div>

<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: и не забудьте убрать все `onclick="changeState()"`

Comment: @Igor да,точно.) отредактирую,чтоб не запуталась.

Comment: Поздравляю с первой тысячей!

Comment: @Igor благодарю))). Медленно но упорно)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @NatalyRudnitska пожалуйста,для выражения благодарности - принимайте ответ.)